# What's a java equivalent for std::round(double)?

Tags: java, c++

In cpp file I have std::round(double)

Please can I know the equivalent code in Java

**Edit**: I am already using `java.lang.Math.round(double)` and getting match in 99% cases. But in some places iam getting mismatch. For example:

- `std::round(4816.5058) = 4816` and `Math.round(4816.5058) = 4817`
- `std::round(4466.49996) = 4467` and `Math.round(4466.49997) = 4466`

Comment: Thanks for bringing in notice.

Comment: "std::round(4816.5058) = 4816" sounds peculiar, and it's not what I get on my machine. Either you've made some error, or you'll have to look into the details of your dodgy `round` implementation (or maybe it's `double` that's peculiar in your C++ implementation). You could perhaps use JNI to call it directly, or you may find you have to write quite a lot of Java code to emulate that platform-specific dodginess. The second one isn't what I get either, but it is what I get if I cast `4466.49996` to float first.

Comment: @Steve: `std::round(4466.49996) = 4467` sounds dodgy as well. @user462475, why do you *want* incorrect rounding? If you always want to round up, then you should use `ceil()`, but `round` is usually assumed to round to *nearest* integer, and your Java examples do that. I'm not sure what's going on with your `std::round` examples (then again, as I recall, `round` isn't even a part of the C++ standard library, is it?), but the results it gives you seem to be incorrect.

Comment: @jalf: true, just less dodgy than the first one. And you're right, `round` isn't in the C++ standard library, it's from C99.

Answer (score 9):

`java.lang.Math.round(double)`

Comment: iam already using java.lang.Math.round(double) and getting match in 99% cases. But in some places iam getting mismatch. for example std::round(4816.5058)= 4816 Math.round(4816.5058) = 4817 example 2: std::round(4466.49996) = 4467 Math.round(4466.49997) = 4466

Comment: @user462475: For your future questions: Please don't hide such important details like the one in your above comment when you ask your question.

Comment: Your examples at least from the java side look correct to me. If anything I would say the results from c++ look wrong. It looks like Java in this instance is more precise.

Comment: @user462475: `double` types, in general, tend to have more precision than they do accuracy. It looks like your C++ results are actually wrong (according to half-up rounding; there are other kinds), I'm guessing because of accuracy issues. The Java `double` type also has accuracy issues, though apparently they're not showing up in your two examples (as the half-up rounding is correct). (Java offers other number types for perfect accuracy, notably `BigDecimal`. But you lose some speed, which is why "traditional" `double` types have accuracy limitations.)

Comment: +1 @Kevin D and @0xA3: This happens many times that the important part why the users comes to ask question at SO is hid.

Comment: @user462475: Just for completeness: If you want more control over the rounding process, you might look at `BigDecimal`'s `setScale` and `round` methods. They let you specify what kind of rounding you want (although again, for ordinary half-up rounding, Java's answers in your examples are correct): http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html